# Firemonkey: How to align properly label on the right?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

If I do

```
RectangleCont.beginUpdate;

myText1 := TText.Create(RectangleCont);
myText1.parent := RectangleCont;
myText1.text := 'a long text'; 
myText1.Position.x := RectangleCont.width - myText1.width; // 150px for exemple
myText1.align := TalignLayout.right;

myText2 := TText.Create(RectangleCont);
myText2.parent := RectangleCont;
myText2.text := 'OK';
myText2.Position.x := RectangleCont.width - myText1.width - myText2.width; // 50px for exemple
myText2.align := TalignLayout.right;

myText3 := TText.Create(RectangleCont);
myText3.parent := RectangleCont;
myText3.text := 'OK';
myText3.Position.x := RectangleCont.width - myText1.width - myText2.width - myText3.width; // 0px for exemple
myText3.align := TalignLayout.right;

RectangleCont.EndUpdate;
```

I will have `<myText1><myText3><myText2>` instead of `<myText3><myText2><myText1>`

**Note**: if I put shorter text in `myText1.text` then it works properly.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: try using `myText1.align := TAlignLayout.MostRight`

Comment: Also setting position is meaningless, because automatic alignment will override it.

Comment: yes, i know about TAlignLayout.MostRight, but what if i have 3 Texts? myText1, myText2 and myText3 ? also normally (and i think it's the case, else it's a big mistake in delphi) in a normal world setting position must not be meaningless because align must be done regarding the original position of the control(s)

Comment: Ok, FMX has some ill logic that DOES depend on original x position plus width of control. Take a look at FMX.Types AlignObjects procedure - specifically InsertBefore function.  
If you cannot align all those controls properly then only course of action is either manual setup or using additional containers so you always have only two controls in same level that must be aligned.

Comment: thanks, yes and i think that in tokyo this is even worse than in berlin :( https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17172 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Delphi `Align` property is good for most situations, but when you have more rare needs, it is not difficult to write your own resize event. Simply skip setting the `Align` and `Position` properties in your code, and instead use this code (it is untested, but I think you get the idea, in case I forgot something):

```
...
RectangleCont.OnResize := DoResizeRectangle;
...


procedure TMainForm.DoResizeRectangle(aSender: TObject);
var lParent: TControl;
begin
  lParent := TControl(aSender);
  myText1.Height := lParent.Height;
  myText2.Height := lParent.Height;
  myText3.Height := lParent.Height;
  myText1.Position.Point := PointF(lParent.Width-myText1.Width, 0);
  myText2.Position.Point := PointF(myText1.Position.X-myText2.Width, 0);
  myText3.Position.Point := PointF(myText2.Position.X-myText3.Width, 0);
end;
```