# Simulate Align position in Delphi Custom Panel

Tags: delphi, alignment, panel

I'm building a custom panel in Delphi XE5 and I'm having a hard time simulating a new **"Gravity"** property where I can combine two coordinates (like Right + Bottom) and the effect is similar to "Align" however, it does not resize the object, direction. The main problem I encountered is to simulate this behavior. My initial intention was to create a panel in memory with the same "Parent" in my custom panel and then align to the position defined in "Gravity" overwriting the "SetBounds" method. It's working, but a bit precarious, especially in "Design Time". **Could someone suggest me how to more effectively simulate this alignment using VCL?**

```
function TZPanel.GetPosition: TCustomPanel;
    var
      sid: TZSide;
      anch: TAnchors;
      panTest: TPanel;
      function getGravity(al: TAlign): TRect;
      var
        panGravity: TPanel;
        I: Integer;
      begin
        try
          //Self.Visible := False;

          panGravity:= TPanel.Create(Self);
          panGravity.BevelInner  := panTest.BevelInner;
          panGravity.BevelOuter  := panTest.BevelOuter;
          panGravity.BevelWidth  := panTest.BevelWidth;
          panGravity.BorderWidth := panTest.BorderWidth;
          panGravity.ParentBackground := True;
          panGravity.SetBounds(panTest.Left, panTest.Top, panTest.Width, panTest.Height);
          panGravity.Parent:= Self.Parent;
          panGravity.Align := al;

          Result:= panGravity.BoundsRect;
        finally
          panGravity.Destroy;
          Self.Visible := True;
        end;
      end;

    begin
      panTest := TPanel.Create(Self);
      panTest.Align   := Align;
      panTest.Anchors := Anchors;
      panTest.BevelInner  := BevelInner;
      panTest.BevelOuter  := BevelOuter;
      panTest.BevelWidth  := BevelWidth;
      panTest.BorderWidth := BorderWidth;
      panTest.SetBounds(Left, Top, Width, Height);

      if (FGravity = []) then
      begin
        //
      end
      else
      begin
        panTest.Align := alCustom;
        anch := [];

        for sid in FGravity do
        begin
          case sid of
            sTop:
            begin
              panTest.Top := getGravity(alTop).Top;
              anch := anch + [akTop];
            end;

            sRight:
            begin
              panTest.Left := getGravity(alRight).Left;
              anch := anch + [akRight];
            end;

            sBottom:
            begin
              panTest.Top := getGravity(alBottom).Top;
              anch := anch + [akBottom];
            end;

            sLeft:
            begin
              panTest.Left := getGravity(alLeft).Left;
              anch := anch + [akLeft];
            end;
          end;
        end;
        panTest.Anchors := anch;
      end;
      Result := panTest;
    end;
```

Comment: see the code of my function (shame) that calculates the new position of the panel

Comment: Newer Delphi versions offer TRelativePanel which might be the control you are looking for:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_the_Relative_Panel

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE5.

Comment: I don't understand anything, you are creating panels to copy them properties. Why can't the panel do what a panel can do? I don't even understand what it is that it is supposed do be doing. I suggest you to provide a [mcve] so that anyone interested can run and see it.

Comment: The above function only gets a TCustomPanel with the new computed position. it does this by creating a Tpanel in memory and setting its "Align" to get the "Top" and "Left" properties after the native method of this property reposition the TPanel in memory.

Comment: AnselmoMS: is it really necessary to use an "internal" panel to do the calculations for you? I mean, this is not rocket science, so do the calculations yourself. That gives you more control too.

Comment: See this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084850

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: That's exactly what I'd like to avoid. But as the property created "Gravity" should consider the "Align" property of the other controls it will touch on, I do not know how to do it more smoothly than by taking advantage of the already existing calculation that delphi itself already does with the "Align."

Comment: @Hans I'm sorry but I did not understand your suggestion.

Comment: @AnselmoMS: As I said, do the calculation on your own. Do not use a hidden control to do it for you. It is not that complicated.